# iweb pages are downloading rather than viewing

Tags: iweb

I'm having an issue with a friends iWeb website - http://www.africanhopecrafts.org. Rather than pages viewing they want to download instead but they're all html files. I've tried messing with my htaccess file to see if that was affecting it but nothings working.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your friend's web site is dishing up the wrong MIME type. The web server might be malconfigured, but the page can override the `content-type` responde header by adding a `<meta>` tag to the page's `<head>` like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="ISO-8859-1" />
```

(where the charset in use reflects that of the actual web page.)

If the page is being served up with the correct `content-type`, the browser might be malconfigured to not handle that content type. Does the problem occur for everybody, or just you? IS the problem dependent on the browser in use?

You can sniff the content-type by installing Firefox's [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) plug in. Fire up Firefox, start TamperData and fetch the errant web page via Firefox. Examining the response headers for the request should tell you what `content-type` the page is being served up with.

Comment: Yeah the content type right now is: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />